# Python subprocess.run() to for: kill -HUP `ps -C gunicorn fch -o pid | head -n 1`

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I need a Python script `subprocess.run()` call for the following:

```
kill -HUP `ps -C gunicorn fch -o pid | head -n 1`
```

This can't be one long concatenation

```
subprocess.run(["kill","-HUP","ps","-C","gunicorn","fch","-o","pid","|","head","-n","1"])
```

How to read the `ps -C gunicorn fch -o pid | head -n 1` portion into `subprocess.run` so it is interpreted by `"kill","-HUP"` as a quoted string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backticks in your original shell code makes a whole separate subprocess for the call to `ps`. The pipe actually does another process creation, for `head`!

If you want to do that in pure Python (rather than delegating it all to a shell), you probably want to do at least one additional `subprocess` call. You probably don't need the one for `head`, since you can easily read one line of output yourself inside Python.

Try something like:

```
ps_process = subprocess.Popen(["ps","-C","gunicorn","fch","-o","pid"],
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pid_string = next(ps_process.stdout).decode().strip()
subprocess.run(["kill","-HUP", pid_string])
```

It's also possible that you can send the `HUP` signal directly from Python, rather than by calling the `kill` program. And heck, there's probably a module that would let you look up the PIDs of other running programs.

Comment: Great with following edits worked fine! Changes: 1) `popen` to `Popen`, and 2)  decode and strip leading whitespace from `pid_string` using `pid_string = next(ps_process.stdout).decode('utf-8').strip()`.

Comment: I'm glad my answer got you pointed in the right direction. I don't have a unix-based system right now, so I was writing some of that speculatively and couldn't test my code (though the `popen` vs `Popen` thing I knew about and should have fixed). I've updated my answer with your updates!